# Spinner with Firebase on Fragment

Tags: android

I want to create spinner with firebase, but when I'm running and click the spinner, the application is error and this is the message :

**java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference**

this my code in Fragment

```
 spinner = view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        names = new ArrayList<>();
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        databaseReference.child("spinners").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot chilSnap:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String spinnerName = chilSnap.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                    names.add(spinnerName);
                    if (spinnerName!=null){
                        names.add(spinnerName);
                    }
                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, names);
                arrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
                spinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there a specific line which it refers to generating an error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check

```
chilSnap.child("name")
```

can be null, add a check

```
String spinnerName =  chilSnap.child("name")!= null ? chilSnap.child("name").getValue(String.class) :null;
```

and remove the first line  names.add(spinnerName); outside the if block